# Case statement returning a select where query

Tags: sql, select, case

I am having trouble with my logic around this select query.

```
SELECT

ISNULL((SELECT cs_facilities.name from cs_facilities where ci_periodicBillings.facility = cs_facilities.guid),'Unknown') as [Care Centre],

ISNULL((SELECT cs_clients.title + ' ' + cs_clients.forename + ' ' + cs_clients.surname from cs_clients where ci_periodicBillings.client = cs_clients.guid),'Unknown') as [Resident Name],

***CASE WHEN ci_periodicbillings.contributionFunder = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' then 'No Funder' ELSE (select ci_contributionFunders.name from ci_contributionFunders where ci_contributionFunders.guid = ci_periodicBillings.contributionFunder) END as [Contribution Funder],***

ISNULL((SELECT cs_clients.ADMISSION from cs_clients where ci_periodicBillings.client = cs_clients.guid),'') as [Admission Date],

ISNULL(ci_periodicbillings.RATE,'') as [Weekly Rate],

CASE WHEN BILLRES = 1 THEN 'Self Payer' ELSE CASE WHEN BILLRES = 2 THEN 'Top up' ELSE 'Other Funder' END END as [Type of Funding],

ISNULL(ci_periodicbillings.LASTBILL,'') as [Billing Period Start Date],

ISNULL(ci_periodicbillings.NEXTBILL,'') as [Billing Period Next Repeat Date],

CASE WHEN invoiceDaysOffset = 22 then 'In Arrears' ELSE CASE WHEN invoicedaysoffset = -6 then 'In Advance' ELSE '' END END as [Advance or Arrears Billing]


from ci_periodicBillings
where facility = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
and ENDBILL = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
order by [Care Centre], [Resident Name]
```

The problematic line, which I'm sure you experts will spot, is the one highlighted with triple stars.

I am hoping that you can see my logic here. within the ci_periodicbillings table is a column labelled "contributionFunder". This refers to a guid in the table ci_contributionFunders. I want my case statement to say if this is a null guid (i.e. '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') then there is no funder, otherwise if the guid matches the column guid in the ci_periodicbillings table, return me the ci_contributionfunders.name value which is the name of the funder.

Can anyone help me tidy this up?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is the query fails based on the segment starred which is a case statement trying to return the contribution funder name

Comment: Can you be more clear on "the query fails"? What is the error message?

Comment: Hi Gareth - clearly I am not as awake as I thought I was, it was just poorly constructed. Using the case statement in my answer below, it now returns correctly. This is a column that will never return NULL values so an ISNULL clause was not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your error message is, nor can I see anything actually wrong with your query, but in reference to tidying it up, there are a few things I would do.

The first is to remove all the correlated subqueries, and use `LEFT JOIN` instead, and the second is to use table aliases rather than repeating the full table names throughout the query. Finally, I would simplify the case statements rather than nesting them:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(f.Name, 'Unknown') AS [Care Centre],
        ISNULL(c.title + ' ' + c.forename + ' ' + c.surname, 'Unknown') AS [Resident Name],
        ISNULL(cf.Name, 'No Funder') AS [Contribution Funder],
        ISNULL(c.ADMISSION, '') AS [Admission Date],
        ISNULL(pb.RATE,'') AS [Weekly Rate],
        CASE pb.BILLRES
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Self Payer' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Top up' 
            ELSE 'Other Funder' 
        END AS [Type of Funding],
        ISNULL(pb.LASTBILL,'') AS [Billing Period Start Date],
        ISNULL(pb.NEXTBILL,'') AS [Billing Period Next Repeat Date],
        CASE pb.invoiceDaysOffset
            WHEN 22 THEN 'In Arrears' 
            WHEN -6 THEN 'In Advance' 
            ELSE ''
        END AS [Advance or Arrears Billing]
FROM    ci_periodicBillings AS pb
        LEFT JOIN cs_facilities AS f
            ON f.guid = pb.facility
        LEFT JOIN cs_clients AS c
            ON c.guid = pb.client
        LEFT JOIN ci_contributionFunders AS cf
            ON cf.guid = pb.contributionFunder
            AND pb.contributionFunder != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
WHERE   pb.facility = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
AND     pb.ENDBILL = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```

The last thing I would do, but I have deliberately separated this because it is very much subjective, is switch to the `Alias = <Expression>` syntax that SQL Server allows, rather than `<Expression> AS Alias`. I find this much more legible since you immediately see with a scan down the select list which column you are looking at. Aaron Bertrand has written a [good article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) that more or less exactly mirrors my feeling on the subject.

```
SELECT  [Care Centre] = ISNULL(f.Name, 'Unknown'),
        [Resident Name] = ISNULL(c.title + ' ' + c.forename + ' ' + c.surname, 'Unknown'),
        [Contribution Funder] = ISNULL(cf.Name, 'No Funder'),
        [Admission Date] = ISNULL(c.ADMISSION, ''),
        [Weekly Rate] = ISNULL(pb.RATE,''),
        [Type of Funding] = CASE pb.BILLRES
                                WHEN 1 THEN 'Self Payer' 
                                WHEN 2 THEN 'Top up' 
                                ELSE 'Other Funder' 
                            END,
        [Billing Period Start Date] = ISNULL(pb.LASTBILL,''),
        [Billing Period Next Repeat Date] = ISNULL(pb.NEXTBILL,''),
        [Advance or Arrears Billing] = CASE pb.invoiceDaysOffset
                                            WHEN 22 THEN 'In Arrears' 
                                            WHEN -6 THEN 'In Advance' 
                                            ELSE ''
                                        END
FROM    ci_periodicBillings AS pb
        LEFT JOIN cs_facilities AS f
            ON f.guid = pb.facility
        LEFT JOIN cs_clients AS c
            ON c.guid = pb.client
        LEFT JOIN ci_contributionFunders AS cf
            ON cf.guid = pb.contributionFunder
            AND pb.contributionFunder != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
WHERE   pb.facility = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
AND     pb.ENDBILL = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: Hi Gareth - that looks much cleaner than my work, but there is one thing I struggle with when switching to a JOIN structured query and that is adding multiple WHERE clauses at the end. In my original query I had about 4 where clauses including - where pb.ENDBILL = '01/01/1900' - could you tell me how you would get this flexibility into your formatting?

Comment: Sorry, not sure why I missed them off. I have just added them into the answer. The structure of the `WHERE` is not affected by the JOINs.

Comment: One question - I can see the result but can you explain how this syntax is working:      LEFT JOIN ci_contributionFunders AS cf
            ON cf.guid = pb.contributionFunder
            AND pb.contributionFunder != '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

Comment: This is just an additional clause in the join, saying I don't want any rows from `ci_contributionFunders` where `pb.contributionFunder` = '000...' -  this way you don't need to do the case satement `CASE WHEN pb.contributionFunder = '000...`, you can just use `ISNULL(cf.Name, 'unknown')` because any rows where the contribution funder is 0 will not return a result for cf.name

Comment: Hi, I am having a go at Alias = Expression now, which is going well, a few questions though. 1 - Is there a setting in SQL to formally adopt this switch as I keep running into a problem when i open a [ bracket of trying to reference a column/table/db and autopopulating. I quite like the autopopulation feature so would like to keep it if possible. 2 - the CASE query isn't working well with numbers - see this isn't working: [Sales Ledger Transaction Type] = CASE id.amount 
          WHEN > 0.00 THEN 'Invoice'  
          WHEN < 0.00 THEN 'Credit Note' 
          Else 'No Value' 
          END

Comment: here is my error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near '>'. The field 'amount' is a decimal(9,2)

Comment: **1.** I am not sure, I have never used intellisense in SSMS, I don't think there is though. **2.** You can only use equals in a simple [case expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), for other operators (such as inequality), you would need to revert to a searched case expression, e.g. `CASE WHEN Amount > 0.00 THEN 'Invoice' WHEN Amount < 0 THEN 'Credit Note' ELSE 'No Value' END`.

Answer (score 0):

Which dialect is this?

You use `case when ... then ... else case when ... then ...`

But the correct syntax in any dialect I know is:

`case when ... then ... when ... then ... else ... end`

And for your problem I suggest left joining first and then use the `isnull` function.

Comment: Hi I have updated to take into account your syntax - CASE WHEN ci_periodicbillings.contributionFunder = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' then 'No Funder' when ci_periodicbillings.contributionFunder <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN (select ci_contributionFunders.name from ci_contributionFunders.guid = ci_periodicBillings.contributionFunder) END as [Contribution Funder], - This is just a Select query in SQL management studio. It still returns a fault and the (SELECT) part is underlined. I am not sure how to express the join/isnull here..

Comment: (1) This is more appropriate as a comment.  (2) All versions of SQL that support `case` statements allow nested `case` statements.  The syntax may be unorthodox, but it is correct.

Comment: I just realised my query was badly written and fixed it - sorry to have wasted your time!

Answer (score 0):

Using your syntax, the case statement worked with:

```
CASE WHEN ci_periodicbillings.contributionFunder = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' then 'No Funder' when ci_periodicbillings.contributionFunder <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' THEN (select ci_contributionFunders.name from ci_contributionFunders where ci_contributionFunders.guid = ci_periodicBillings.contributionFunder) END as [Contribution Funder],
```